# Best way to handle return types during catching exceptions in Scala

Tags: scala

How do you handle return types when we are catching exceptions? Are there any best practices?

```
class Test {

  val emptymap = Map[Int,Int]()
  val divisor = 100
  def handleInt ( i : Int) : Map[Int, Int] = {
    try {

      val output = divisor / i
      Map(divisor -> output)
    } catch {
      case e : ArithmeticException => e.printStackTrace(); emptymap
      case e : NumberFormatException => e.printStackTrace(); emptymap
    }
  }

  def handleIntTry ( i : Int) : Map[Int, Int] = {
    val answer = Try(divisor / i)
    answer match {
      case x : Success[Int] => Map(divisor -> answer.get)
      case x : ArithmeticException => { x.printStackTrace(); emptymap}
      case x : NumberFormatException => { x.printStackTrace(); emptymap}
    }
  }
}
```

Are they both correct? which would be the better way to handle these situations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second is incorrect but for reasons which have nothing to do with "handling return types when we are catching exceptions".

1. It's pointless to use `Try` and then immediately match on the answer; it's just a more verbose and slower version of `try-catch`. `Try` is useful when you are going to pass it somewhere, or maybe combine multiple calculations.
2. Even neglecting that, the correct match would be

   ```
   answer match {
     case Success(x) => Map(divisor -> x)
     case Failure(x) => { x.printStackTrace(); emptymap}
   }
   ```

   (no need to handle `ArithmeticException` and `NumberFormatException` separately if you are going to do the same in both cases).

What applies to both versions:

3. you create `emptymap` in advance, even if the exception isn't thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Either way works. Here's a 3rd option.

```
def handleInt(i :Int) :Map[Int,Int] =
  Try(divisor / i).fold({
    case x : ArithmeticException   => x.printStackTrace(); emptymap
    case x : NumberFormatException => x.printStackTrace(); emptymap
  }, answer => Map(divisor -> answer))
```